# Validate Time Up for Windows 8 game app c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, timer, countdown

Have a textbox that displays countdown from 2 minutes for my app. The countdown timer works but when I tell it some things to do after it goes to zero it still keeps counting down after 0 which is definitely not right. I think my problem is how I checking the text itself but I'm not sure.

Here is current code for the timer:

```
 private void Time_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScoreNum.Text = Game.Score.ToString();

        if (Time.Text == "0:00") //this is where I think the problem is
        {
            Game.Timer.Stop();
            GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            GameOverFlashing.Begin();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption, and here is what you can do to fix it:

```
if (Time.Text.Equals("0:00"))
{
    // your code here
}
```

The `Equals` method checks if the two strings have the same value, whereas before you were checking if the two strings are the same instance of a string. This is a very easy mistake to make, but because strings are not primitive types, like `int` and `double`, you cannot simply check their equivalence using the `==` operator.

Comment: Ivan's analysis is correct in theory, however, [== uses Equals to test for both reference and value equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx), so your original code would have the same outcome as the recommended answer.  Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I could have sworn that's how it worked. I must have been thinking about java. Oh well.

Comment: I just set the visibility to collapsed when the time is up for now and my events all show up when time is up so it worked out.